# chrome downgrade package missing in archive

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I'm trying to install chrome v75 in a clean ubuntu16.04 container, but the following file it requests are missing from archive:

```
# apt install --fix-missing -f ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
:
E: Klarte ikke å skaffe http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dh-python/dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
```

if I look up the archive it has a 1 and 1.2 but not a 1.1:

```
[ ] dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1.2.dsc   2019-08-16 03:28    1.8K
[ ] dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1.2.tar.xz    2019-08-16 03:28    78K
[ ] dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1.2_all.deb   2019-08-16 03:28    72K
[ ] dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1.dsc 2015-11-04 21:16    1.4K
[ ] dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1.tar.xz  2015-11-04 21:16    78K
[ ] dh-python_2.20151103ubuntu1_all.deb 2015-11-04 22:17    73K
```

How can I fix the deb file dependencies, or are there anywhere to donwload this. I should have tagged v75-container before it updated to v76.

```
# dpkg --info google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 58939226 bytes: control archive=10386 bytes.
    1188 bytes,    13 lines      control
   16906 bytes,   457 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
   12983 bytes,   344 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/sh
    1385 bytes,    42 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/sh
 Package: google-chrome-stable
 Version: 75.0.3770.80-1
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Chrome Linux Team <chromium-dev@chromium.org>
 Installed-Size: 203915
 Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.0)
 Depends: ca-certificates, fonts-liberation, libappindicator3-1, libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libatk-bridge2.0-0 (>= 2.5.3), libatk1.0-0 (>= 2.2.0), libatspi2.0-0 (>= 2.9.90), libc6 (>= 2.16), libcairo2 (>= 1.6.0), libcups2 (>= 1.4.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.5.12), libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10), libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~), libnss3 (>= 2:3.22), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libuuid1 (>= 2.16), libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1), libx11-xcb1, libxcb1 (>= 1.6), libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4), libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.3), libxrender1, libxss1, libxtst6, lsb-release, wget, xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2)
 Recommends: libu2f-udev
 Provides: www-browser
 Section: web
 Priority: optional
 Description: The web browser from Google
  Google Chrome is a browser that combines a minimal design with sophisticated technology to make the web faster, safer, and easier.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out container repo was outdated, so `apt update` fixed it.

```
# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 75.0.3770.80
```